# Resize rectangle corner

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I'm working on an image editor, there are some shape controls like rectangle, eclipse etc with drag drop feature on canvas and they are re-sizable(one corner is fixed, other three are re-sizable), attached a screen shot below:

[image]

I'd like to only resize the seleted corner, other three will be fixed, any ideas?

**DaveRook Edit**

In Photoshop, this is achieved by [wrapping](http://csscreme.com/tutorials/photoshop-tutorials/warp_tool_effect_photoshop_tutorial) (under transforms)! This means re-drawing that corner un-proportionally to the rest of the image.

Comment: Are you asking how to ['warp' (Photoshop term)](http://csscreme.com/tutorials/photoshop-tutorials/warp_tool_effect_photoshop_tutorial) your image?

Comment: @DaveRook sort of, but not image i want to wrap shape any ideas how to

Comment: I'm not sure your picture reflects your description: in your picture you have one fixed corner, but you describe a situation with three fixed corners.  Can you provide an example where the picture and text match better so we can understand what your goal is?

Comment: @DanPuzey - I've edited the question, see the link under wrapping (or in my first comment) which explains to technique

Comment: @DaveRook: Yes, I see your edit and your added link, but that doesn't seem to match the original post, and SizS hasn't confirmed either way.

Comment: @dan see my comment i confirmed it, one more thing to add, im able do x,y,z-axis projection on shape, but thats not solving my problem

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do a few things to achieve resizing of your rectangle.

1. a drag handle (something for the user to click and move).
2. to calculate the new height and width of your rectangle based upon the mouse position when the drag handle is being moved.
3. to update the height and width of the rectangle.

There is no shortcut here, but [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702192/using-a-handle-to-resize-in-silverlight) should be enough to get you started